# CSS - Making columns inline-flex with not full height

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox, materialize

I'm making something as "Trello" or "Zenhub" board (Kanban) and I ran into an issue. I have 4 columns in a div#board with are display: inline flex, so everything is nicely in line and there is fully working horizontal stack of columns, but It also made same height for every column. 
Is there any solution, so each column would be just with min-height: 400px; if there is no card in?

[Here is JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lupp_/xaznt7kd/11/)

```
#board {
  overflow-x: auto;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 154px) !important;
  padding: 0 2rem 2rem 0;
}

div.column-container {
  display: inline-flex;
}
/* -= COLUMN =- */

div.column {
  order: 1;
  width: 400px;
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 2rem;
  border-radius: .8rem;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default your container is setting its items to use align-items stretch, that means that the items will fill the container's height, you can overwrite this behavior setting your items to flex-start.

https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/puhyo7oa/

```
div.column-container {
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ^^ It's working .. I didn't know that solution was that simple.